# How to Process Type 2 Slowly Changing Dimensions using SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a historical table with data as bellow    :

In my case the `product id` (110,111,112) had changed the `price` that way i have the same product with the value of the `product_updateDate` also sometimes i can have the same duplicate data with no information changed

```
+------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| id   | product_id | product_name | product_Price |       product_addDate       |   product_UpdateDate    |      Insertdate_DB      | Updatedate_DB  |
+------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|    1 |        110 |    DELL      |          1000 |    2017-03-01 08:00:00.000  | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
|    2 |        111 |    HP        |           900 |    2017-03-01 08:00:00.000  | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 3    |        112 |    Mac       |          1300 |    2017-03-01 08:00:00.000  | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 4    |        113 |   Lenovo     |           950 |    2017-03-01 08:00:00.000  | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 5    |        110 |   DELL       |           900 |    2017-03-04 08:00:00.000  | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 6    |        111 |    HP        |           800 |    2017-03-04 08:00:00.000  | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
| 7    |        112 |    Mac       |           120 |    2017-03-04 08:00:00.000  | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL           |
+------+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

What i want is doing an Update Query to get the result as bellow:

```
 +----+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| id | product_id | product_name | product_Price |     product_addDate     |   product_UpdateDate    |      Insertdate_DB      | Updatedate_DB |
+----+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|  1 |        110 | DELL         |          1000 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | GETDATE()     |
|  2 |        111 | HP           |           900 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | GETDATE()     |
|  3 |        112 | Mac          |          1300 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | GETDATE()     |
|  4 |        113 | Lenovo       |           950 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2017-03-06 10:00:00.000 | NULL          |
|  5 |        110 | DELL         |           900 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL          |
|  6 |        111 | HP           |           800 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL          |
|  7 |        112 | Mac          |           120 | 2017-03-04 08:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 2017-03-07 10:00:00.000 | NULL          |
+----+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

The query as bellow can update the `product_UpdateDate`

```
update tablename set product_UpdateDate=
case when tablename.product_UpdateDate is null then t.product_UpdateDate
else null end
from tablename 
join tablename t on tablename.product_id=t.product_id
and t.ID<>tablename.id `
```

But also i want to change the `Updatedate_DB` with the `GETDATE()` value when i try to do update this column  all rows have the value `GETDATE()` but i want change only the rows that the value have change

Thanks for help

Comment: I don't understand the sample data you have provided in the context of your question. You talk about a change in product_id and price but the only change is in the format of the id key (possibly changing from char to int) and the addition of the column indicating the first duplicate entries occurring after the change in id format. Please clarify what the changes are and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think row 1, 7 or 5 in the example you provided are wrong. You should always have one product id with a product_update = NULL, right? if that's the case, then you want to implement a type 2 slowly changing dimension in a SP, right?

Comment: @Alan can you please see my update ?

Comment: @asemprini87 please see my update

Comment: Are you going to update the table based on another table (maybe stage) or are you updating rows one at a time with data from an application?

Comment: @asemprini87 I think he want update the same table using a `SQL Query`